# Search Box which instantly filters a html table with ATK?

Tags: html, atk4

What I am basicly triyng to do is this [Search Box which instantly filters a html table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375235/search-box-which-instantly-filters-a-html-table).

I have a table with contents and a textfield. While I write on the textfield, I want the table to change so that only the matches are visible. without pushing a button.
Datatables seems like a solution but I don't know ow to integrate it with ATK.

The reason I write this is because I'm not smart enough to make this work with ATK. Not even Google managed to change that. 
Anyone that can point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Filtering should be done on server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example you can see how Autocomplete field is implemented in ATK here
https://github.com/atk4/autocomplete

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not really what I am after. I'm more looking for a way to make the shown resutls in the table be filtered while I'm typing. Either by hiding the rows that don't match or by actually doing a new sql request.

Comment: That's exactly what Autocomplete field does behind the scenes. It filters results on server side on every key press.